# Electrical problem;maximum power transfer;confusion

Tags: power

In the network of figure,the maximum power is delivered to \$R_L\$ if its value is ______ \$ ?\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcvY2k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

where, \$ I_1 \$ is the current flowing through \$ AB \$ via \$ A \$ to \$ B \$

My Approach: 
we know for maximum power delivered to \$ R_L \$ :
\$ R_L = R_{TH}\$ where \$ R_{TH} \$ is the Thevenin's Resistance
To calculate  \$ R_{TH} \$ :
**Process 1**:
\$ R_{TH}= \frac{V_{TH}}{I_N} \$ or  \$ R_{TH}= \frac{V_{OC}}{I_{SC}} \$
For \$ V_{OC} \$ :

[image: schematic]
Applying KCL at node \$A\$ : $$0.5 \times I_1 = \frac{V_{OC}}{20} + I_1$$ $$\implies V_{OC}=- 10I_1$$ and $$I_1=\frac{V_{OC}-50}{40}$$ so,after solving for \$ V_{OC} \$ we get: $$V_{OC}=10V$$
In a similar fashion we calculate \$ I_{SC} \$ by shorting \$ R_L \$ and get $$I_{SC}=0.625A$$  $$\therefore R_{TH}= \frac{10}{0.625}=16\Omega$$
Hence,maximum power is delivered to \$R_L\$ if its value is \$ 16\Omega \$

**Process2**:

[image: schematic]
Here, \$ R_{TH}=\frac{V_a}{I_a} \$ where \$ I_a \$ is the current flowing out from \$ V_a \$ voltage source
so, \$ I_1 = \frac{100-50}{40}= \frac{5}{4} \Omega \$
so applying KCL at node \$ A \$ : $$0.5 \times \frac{5}{4} + I_a = \frac{100}{20} + \frac{5}{4}$$ $$\implies I_a=\frac{45}{8} A$$ $$\therefore R_{TH}=\frac{100}{\frac{45}{8}}= 17.78\Omega$$
Hence,maximum power is delivered to \$R_L\$ if its value is \$ 17.78\Omega \$

Thus,which process is right? please help....

Comment: Which direction does the current flow? Mark it on your diagrams. Process 2 doesn’t have the same circuit so how might it be the same?

Comment: Current ( \$ I_1 \$ ) is flowing from A to B

Comment: @ Andy aka  In process 2 : we have added an arbitrary ( \$ V_a \$ ) Voltage source in place of \$ R_{L} \$ to find \$ R_{TH} \$ ........i guess it's another process to evaluate \$ R_{TH} \$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this answer is a bit old but I saw it and wanted to answer it in case the OP is still waiting for an answer.

### Checking Power for Both Processes

My first thought when seeing this question was to calculate the power at 16Ω at 17.78Ω and see which is larger. This way I know which process to focus in on for looking for the error.

Using the original circuit, here is the equation using KCL at Node A:

$$
-0.5I_1 + \frac{V_a}{20} + \frac{V_a}{R_L} + I_1 = 0
$$

**Note:** I usually write KCL such that all of the currents are coming **out** of the node. This is why there is a negative for the dependent source.

There are two unknowns in the equation above so we define \$I_1\$ in terms of \$V_a\$:

$$
I_1 = \frac{V_a - 50}{40}
$$

Plugging \$I_1\$ into the KCL equation and solving for \$V_a\$ gives

$$
V_a = \frac{0.625}{0.0625 + \frac{1}{R_L}} \\
\\
V_a(R_L = 16 \Omega) = 5V \\
V_a(R_L = 17.78 \Omega) = 5.2634V
$$

The power can easily be calculated with the voltage and load resistance known (\$P = \frac{V^2}{R}\$):

$$
P(R_L = 16 \Omega) = 1.5625V \\
P(R_L = 17.78 \Omega) = 1.558V
$$

This leads me to believe that the first process you used is correct and there is an error in your second process.

### What's the Issue Then?

It's been awhile since I've had circuits 101 and to be honest, I haven't used thevenin resistances much since then.

According to [AllAboutCircuits](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/thevenin-theorem-dependent-source-circuits/), when using a test source, you must turn off **independent** sources!

Let us repeat the calculation with the dependent source off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqAg75.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We can calculate \$I_1\$ to be \$100 / 40 \Omega = 2.5A\$.

Applying KCL at node A:

$$
-I_1 * 0.5 + 100 / 20 - I_a + I_1 = 0 \\
-1.25A + 5A + 2.5A = I_a \\
I_a = 6.25A \\
R_{th} = \frac{V_a}{I_a} = \frac{100}{6.25} = 16 \Omega
$$

**Long story short, you forgot to turn off the independent source.**